# how to get click event of text box with in an li using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of text box within `<li>'s`. How can I get the click event of the text box?

They are placed inside a `<div>` nested as shown below.
the lis's section is dynamically created with jquery .. but the click event is not triggerd as like . i have tried the jquery answers posted in dynamic

```
<div>
   <ul>
        <li><input type="text"></li>
        <li><input type="text"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your code didn't paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('li').on('click','input[type="text"]', function(){
//code goes here//
});
```

There you go.

Comment: wow this one absolut right  , iam checking the .live jquery function is deprecated in jquery new version , but didnt worked but , this one does magic. thanks

Comment: Its working.. fine, i have been using .live some times it not works due to jquery incopatiblity .. now its fine thanks

Comment: @PatsyIssa I hope now you don't have any issue with my edited answer  any more  :)

Comment: @rahularyansharma When an answer works, does what was asked and is accepted editing a previous one that took 2 steps to get to it seems a bit illogical :)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery selectors are similar to CSS Selectors. You can use the same pattern and apply event handler to the elements. But, It would be very easy if you identify your code using class and id. Like

```
<div id="mydiv">
<!-- Adding ID to the div like this will help you to target your event handler
     To a set of required elements only -->

   <ul>
        <li><input type="text"></li>
        <li><input type="text"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then you can catch the click event on the text box very simple as

```
$("#mydiv input[type='text']").on('click', function() {
// ^ Isn't this as same as CSS?

    console.log("I am clicked");
});
```

With your markup even though you apply event handler it will be general and will apply to all the text boxes inside a div throughout the page.

If you dont want to change your markup and want to apply the function to all the input boxes. A general version of this code would be:

```
$("div :text").on('click', function() {
    console.log('I am clicked');
});
```

Comment: SO question not have any Id for that div

Comment: Yes i already read that, we are here to give answer of SO questions instead of giving them suggestions to change the current situation . sorry if i hurt you ..

Comment: @rahularyansharma On really, we are not allow to give suggestion now? Why don't you bring that up on, [meta]?

Comment: the text are dynamically append using jquery , even the jquery functions are working the jquery clcik in not triggered in the dynamic context

Comment: @anoop, Oh.. So you wanted event delegation too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div ul li input[type='text']").click (function () {
           // Do your stuff here
});
```

Simply giving `$("input[type='text']")` works fine for all the text boxes irrespective of their positions.

Comment: i have tried this one but dint work, the text box in li are dynamically created with in the each text box in correspoding link on click of a button. I nned to get the click of the input box to perform ajax call..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('div li input:text').click(function(){
    //do
})
```

Comment: typo mistake instead of div you use only di :)

Comment: the text are dynamically append using jquery , even the jquery functions are working the jquery clcik in not triggered in the dynamic context

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div ul li input[type=text]').click(function () {
    alert('HI');
}

);
```

[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/hjtBA/129/)

**EDITED**

```
$("body").on("click", "div ul li input[type=text]", function(event){
    alert('HI');
});
```

[UPDATED JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/hjtBA/132/)

Comment: hi it very helpful , but doesnt work, the li with the text is dynamically created that may be the reason

Comment: the text box in li are dynamically created with in the each text box in correspoding li with  on click of a button. I need to get the click of the input box to perform ajax call

Comment: @anoop I don't understand you are asking me after accepting answer, Does that answer didn't answer your question  ?

Comment: yes that works fine in static dil> ul_>li>input way but didnt worked when the input type dynalically generated

Comment: @rahularyansharma so editing your answer by adding mine to it ?

Comment: @PatsyIssa I just edited answer just after getting comments from OP. I hope you already noticed his comments on this answer.

Comment: @rahularyansharma and i hope you noticed that you simply added the exact code from the accepted answer :)

Comment: I never try to copy any one answer either its accepted or not.I am not here for reputation. and He changed accepted answer already three times for this question . You can check also jsfiddle as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$("input[name$='TextboxId']").click(function()

{
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ia have found the answer. After i have tried all the answer finnaly got it. in order to trigger the click event of dynamically created text box we have to use live along with the answer

```
$("#location input[type='text']").live("click", function(){
    alert("Test");
});
```

Comment: Ugh, please no. The `.live()` function was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed entirely in jQuery 1.9 - if you update to that (or a later) version this code will stop working entirely. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (jQuery 1.7+ only) instead: $('#location').on('click', 'input[type="text"]', function() {...});` - assuming the `#location` element is not dynamic, and only the text boxes are.